# How can I declare output of a query as variable in Orcale SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a query that shows the average salary of employees who are in a specific department. I use Oracle SQL Developer.

[image: See tables here]

```
SELECT AVG(salary) from employees
WHERE department_id = 100
```

I gotta use the output of this query in an if statement. For example, I need to write an if statement which outputs "More than 10,000" if the average salary of the employees is more than 10,000 units.

I know how to write an if statement and declare a variable. But I couldn't declare the output of a query as a var. Please just show me another example so that I can do my task on my own.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `case when` expression as follows:

```
SELECT case when AVG(salary) > 10000 then 'More than 10000'
            else 'less than 10000'
       end as res_
 from employees
WHERE department_id = 100
```

Or if you really want the average salary in the variable in anonymous block then you can use `INTO` as follows:

```
DECLARE
  v_avg_sal number;
BEGIN
  SELECT AVG(salary) INTO v_avg_sal from employees
   WHERE department_id = 100;
  -- use v_avg_sal according to your logic here
END;
/
```

Comment: Using if the statement is Mandatory for the task. Thanks for your help!